# XSLT to add attributes to Root Node

Tags: xslt, element

i am looking for a XSLT that should add two attributes "xmlns:xsi" and "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" to my root node.

**Input is:**

```
<Root>
  <Client>mode/Client>
</Root>
```

**Output should be:**

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
  <Client>mode/Client>
</Root>
```

How can i archieve this?

This does only work for **xmlns:xsi** but not for **xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation**:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Input is:**

```
<Root>
  <Client>mode/Client>
</Root>
```

**Output is:**

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Client>mode/Client>
</Root>
```

**EDIT:**
I think i found a solution:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an attribute to the root element, you need to add it to the root element itself, not to the `xsl:element` instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">mySchema.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you know the name of the root element:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that a namespace declaration is not an attribute - hence the difference in behavior you observed. And the **root element** is not the **root node** - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#root-node.